# Tomcat, User Session Storage with JDBCStore, Immediate Session Timeout

Tags: java, session, tomcat, persistence

I am attempting to store user session data in a database. I have followed a few articles and the Tomcat documentation on how to do this.

I am now using Tomcat7 and PostgreSQL and can confirm the INSERTS are working but theres still a problem. Tomcat is inserting the user session into the database and then is immediately deleting it:

Snippet from my Tomcat tomcat7/conf/context.xml:

```
...
<Manager className="org.apache.catalina.session.PersistentManager"           
        maxIdleBackup="1"
        minIdleSwap="0"
        maxIdleSwap="0"
        processExpiresFrequency="1"
        saveOnRestart='true'
        >

        <Store className="org.apache.catalina.session.JDBCStore"                
                connectionURL="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/tomcat?user=[USER]&amp;password=[PASSWORD]"
                driverName="org.postgresql.Driver"
                sessionAppCol="app_name"
                sessionDataCol="session_data"
                sessionIdCol="session_id"
                sessionLastAccessedCol="last_access"
                sessionMaxInactiveCol="max_inactive"
                sessionTable="tomcat_sessions"
                sessionValidCol="valid_session" 
                />
</Manager>
...
```

I have also added this to my tomcat7/conf/catalina.properties:

```
...
org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.ACTIVITY_CHECK=true
org.apache.catalina.STRICT_SERVLET_COMPLIANCE=true
...
```

I have the PostgreSQL JDBC connector in tomcat7/lib.

**Variations I have tried:**

- Tomcat 6
- Tomcat 7
- MySQL
- PostgreSQL

I have also added the following to conf/logging.properties in the hopes I could debug this futher:

```
...
org.apache.catalina.session.PersistentManager.level = ALL
org.apache.catalina.session.PersistentManager.useParentHandlers = true
org.apache.catalina.session.level = ALL
org.apache.catalina.session.useParentHandlers = true
...
```

The table schema is

```
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field         | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| session_id    | varchar(100) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| valid_session | char(1)      | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| max_inactive  | int(32)      | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| last_access   | int(64)      | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| app_name      | varchar(255) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| session_data  | mediumblob   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Tomcat logs show:

```
Jun 27, 2013 2:16:33 PM org.apache.catalina.session.PersistentManagerBase processExpires
FINE: Start expire sessions PersistentManager at 1372338993228 sessioncount 1
Jun 27, 2013 2:16:33 PM org.apache.catalina.session.PersistentManagerBase processMaxIdleSwaps
FINE: Swapping session 22115A5964B70168B1752D5415DAD31C to Store, idle for 36 seconds
Jun 27, 2013 2:16:33 PM org.apache.catalina.session.PersistentManagerBase processExpires
FINE: End expire sessions PersistentManager processingTime 168 expired sessions: 0
```

The postgreSQL logs show:

```
2013-06-27 14:16:33 IST LOG:  execute <unnamed>: INSERT INTO tomcat_sessions (session_id, app_name, session_data, valid_session, max_inactive, last_access) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6)
2013-06-27 14:16:33 IST DETAIL:  parameters: $1 = '22115A5964B70168B1752D5415DAD31C', $2 = '/Catalina/localhost/[SERVLET_NAME]', $3 = '\xaced...f72', $4 = '1', $5 = '1800', $6 = '1372338956718'
2013-06-27 14:16:33 IST LOG:  execute <unnamed>: SELECT session_id FROM tomcat_sessions WHERE app_name = $1
2013-06-27 14:16:33 IST DETAIL:  parameters: $1 = '/Catalina/localhost/[SERVLET_NAME]'
2013-06-27 14:16:33 IST LOG:  execute <unnamed>: SELECT session_id, session_data FROM tomcat_sessions WHERE session_id = $1 AND app_name = $2
2013-06-27 14:16:33 IST DETAIL:  parameters: $1 = '22115A5964B70168B1752D5415DAD31C', $2 = '/Catalina/localhost/[SERVLET_NAME]'
2013-06-27 14:16:33 IST LOG:  execute <unnamed>: DELETE FROM tomcat_sessions WHERE session_id = $1  AND app_name = $2
2013-06-27 14:16:33 IST DETAIL:  parameters: $1 = '22115A5964B70168B1752D5415DAD31C', $2 = '/Catalina/localhost/[SERVLET_NAME]'
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try adding `org.apache.catalina.session.level = FINE` to the bottom of tomcat7/conf/logging.properties. If you then restart Tomcat you should see more session related debug going to the catalina.log (and console). That might give some clues as to what's happening.

Comment: @WillKeeling thanks for the debugging suggestion but I actually already had this added but forgot to mention it in my post. It didn't really give me any additional useful information. I have edited the post to include.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I switched to MySQL database and using BIGINT instead of INT(64). It solved the problem for me...

I have no idea why...Love being a programmer!

Answer (score 2):

There's a bug in Tomcat 7.0.x.  You'll need to upgrade to 7.0.56+  or 8.

https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57016

Answer (score 1):

You need to check a couple of things...

1. Verify that tomcat is actually connecting to the database at all
2. Then once you are sure it is connecting.. does the user have access to update the table tomcat_sessions
3. If you want to add data to the session then all objects need to be serializable or they won't be reloadable

Hope this helps

Comment: - 1. Can't verify that as no log output about it, but intentionally giving it incorrect login details and seeing no difference suggests it isn't even attempting to connect. I was able to use same configuration for a standalone java program using JDBC to connect to the database. **if you have any suggestions here for a way to debug this futher, that would be great** --- - 2. The particular user for the MySQL example show below has full permissions for that database --- - 3. All objects are serializable and are reloadable as I was using file persistence storage successfully before this.

Comment: Tail the mysql server logs to see if connection is being attempted...(probably not as you say).. Also see if you can access the session object from tomcat admin.. it may show you the current persistence as well... and another must is org.apache.catalina.STRICT_SERVLET_COMPLIANCE system property to true for the persistent manager to work correctly...

Comment: MySQL logs confirms successful connection made to database and
_netstat_ linux command confirms that java has established a connection to MySQL and is keeping it open...but still no data being stored in database

Comment: I wonder what character set is being used when inserting? and what your database character set is, perhaps there is a mismatch somewhere there

Comment: When using postgresql it is now successfully inserting, but session immediately timeouts and is then deleted....Session timeout should be set to 30 minutes...